# Высота блока в Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, html, css

Возникла следующая ситуация, обернул контент сайта во `wrapper`, для того, чтобы прижать `footer` к низу страницы. После этого высота Bootstrap блока `content` не устанавливается в процентах. Если быть точнее, то ожидаемый результат отображается в Opera, но в других браузерах не получается.
Вот примерный код страницы (без контента):

```
<html><head>
    <title><?php echo $title;?></title>  
</head>   
<body>
<div class="page-wrapper">                  
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">Контент</div>          
        </div> <!-- End row -->
    </div> <!-- End container -->
    <div class="page-buffer"></div><!-- End buffer -->
</div><!-- End wrapper -->



<div class="page-footer">
    <div class="text-align-center">Футер</div>
</div><!-- End footer -->
</body></html>
```

CSS стили для `wrapper`:

```
 .page-wrapper {
     min-height: 100%;
     margin-bottom: -50px;
 }
 * html .page-wrapper {
     height: 100%;
 }
 .page-buffer {
     height: 50px;
     clear: both;
 }
  .page-footer {
     height: 50px;
 }
```

Хочется, чтобы `container` занимал минимум 90% высоты страницы.

Comment: Писал я об этом как то http://grigoriev.pw/lab/pure-sticky-footer/ , тут и про ваш вариант и про то что его использовать не стоит и про более удачный вариант)

Comment: если высота контента превышает высоту страницы, то футер "замирает" на месте, а страницу можно листать дальше, при этом футер можно пролистать :)

Comment: Если вы про мой вариант, покажите пожалуйста пример, я напишу что не так

Comment: <html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <nav class="header">

        </nav>
        <div class="content">
            
        </div>
        <div class="boofer"></div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
        
    </footer>
</body>
</html>

Comment: у вас для всех элементов height: 100%; - уберите это у body? затем для html position:relative; ну и у body должен быть margin-bottom в высоту футера - это для варианта с футером на абсолюте тоесть где разметка без врапера.

посмотрите на второй вариант, он чище и по мне так менее косячный http://grigoriev.pw/lab/pure-sticky-footer/